# iOS: Complex embedded tableview, how do I scroll up the cells to edit?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've been struggling with this for over a week and tried a ton of solutions here on Stackoverflow and the internet, but I don't seem to get to a solution...

First of all I have rather a complex view hierarchy. Each view contains three subviews. A header, a center, and a footer. The center view contains a tableview. I have it like this, because I want to have the header and footer always visible.

Now what I want is to check if my keyboard hides the textfield which is to edit. If so, scroll the table view so the textfield is at the top of the table for better edit.

But I cannot get it to work. I've started now to code my own class but now I struggle with frame size. First of all here's my code:

```
@implementation MovingTextFieldsIntoViewTableView

@synthesize activeField = _activeField;
@synthesize activeCellIndexPath = _activeCellIndexPath;
@synthesize tableFrameInMainView = _tableFrameInMainView;
@synthesize completeScreen = _completeScreen;

#pragma mark move textfield into view
// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
//If this isn't called the table view acts as a normal table view
// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGRect keyboard = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

    //UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    //self.contentInset = contentInsets;
    //self.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    CGRect visiblePartOfScreen = self.completeScreen;
    visiblePartOfScreen.size.height -= keyboard.size.height;

    CGRect rectOfCellInTableView = [self rectForRowAtIndexPath:self.activeCellIndexPath];

    CGFloat textFieldBottomY = self.tableFrameInMainView.origin.y - self.contentOffset.y + rectOfCellInTableView.origin.y + self.activeField.frame.origin.y + self.activeField.frame.size.height;

    NSLog(@"textFieldBottomY: %f", textFieldBottomY);
    NSLog(@"Screen size: %f", self.completeScreen.size.height);
    NSLog(@"keyboar height: %f", keyboard.size.height);
    NSLog(@"visible screen size: %f", visiblePartOfScreen.size.height);


    CGPoint activeFieldBottomY = CGPointMake(self.activeField.frame.origin.x, textFieldBottomY);


    if (CGRectContainsPoint(visiblePartOfScreen, activeFieldBottomY)) {
        NSLog(@"Keyboard does NOT hide textfield");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Keyboard does hide textfield");
    }
//    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
//        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:activeField.frame animated:YES];
//    }
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
//    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
//    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
//    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

@end
```

As you can see I only want to see first if my function recognizes correctly if a certain textfield is hidden or not. But this doesn't work completely.
The problem must be with one of the properties:

activeField is set (as in Apple's example) directly in begin edit.

activeCellIndexPath is set in the same location as the active field (with the tag of the textfield)

tableFrameInMainView: In the respective viewDidLoad methods of the main view controllers I'm setting the table frame in relation to the main view. This seems to work and gives me the exact same values as set in interface builder with the constraints.

completeScreen: Here I want to have the visible frame of the screen without the keyboard. This **seems to be the problem** at the moment because I guess this one is somehow to big (maybe because of the navigation bar? Or tabbar?) As you see I need this in order to find out with the keyboardSize which part of the screen (with content) is visible and which one is hidden. How do I get here the correct value? My content doesn't extend below the nav bar or tab bar. I mean in the simulator for a 3.5inch iPhone the keyboard covers roughly half of the screen with content. However keyBoard height is 216, whereas my completeScreen.height logs 480...

EDIT:
I've check now the navigationbar height and it is 0. And this is I guess because NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController); results in null from my view controller...however this doesn't make any sense since my navigation controller is working and I've set up everything in XCode Interface Builder?!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will completely solve you problem, but I may give you some advice.

Is your class inheriting from UIViewController?

I've recently had a similar issue, and solved in 1-2 hours by inheriting from UITableViewController, and that class already does all the work on my behalf. 
I'm just not sure if you can do the same and then add all the other views, but I guess that should be possible.

In my case I have a "+" UIBarButton, and when a user was tapping on it, a new cell that contains a UITextField is added at the end of the table, and the text-field should also become first responder, and the table view to scroll accordingly. This is how I did:

```
- (void)onBarButtonAddFolderTap:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    PPFolder *newFolder = [[PPFolder alloc] initWithName:@""];

    [[SessionManager sharedManager] addFolder:newFolder];

    NSIndexPath *indexPathForNewFolder = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([[SessionManager sharedManager].folders count] - 1) inSection:0];

    [self.tableViewFolders insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPathForNewFolder]
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];

    [self.tableViewFolders scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPathForNewFolder atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];

    PPFolderCell *folderCell = [self cellForRow:indexPathForNewFolder.row];

    [folderCell.textFieldFolderName becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Try to subclass UITableViewController and do something similar.
I hope that helped you somehow :)

Comment: Thx for your reply. But I think I cannot subclass UITableViewController in this case since my main view contains three subviews from which only one contains the table view :-/

Comment: Are you creating the subviews programmatically?

Comment: No everything in Interface builder. The subviews are basically just containers..the top subview is just a background image and a label as well as at the bottom. The center subview contains the table view which is basically 90% of the content.

Comment: Well, I kind of found the Solution :).

Inherit from UITableView as I've told you. Then set the header and footer of the table to represent your subviews.

Comment: @ppalancica can you please share how you did that?

Comment: @AlexSorokoletov, the idea is that you need to scroll to the corresponding view first, I mean the view that contains the text field should be visible on the iDevice screen. After that, you should refer to the corresponding textfield inside that cell (there are many ways you can achieve it), and call "becomeFirstResponder".

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 100.0f;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 100.0f;
}

// custom view for header. will be adjusted to default or specified header height
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *viewForHeader = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];

    viewForHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

    return viewForHeader;
}

// custom view for footer. will be adjusted to default or specified footer height
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *viewForFooter = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];

    viewForFooter.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

    return viewForFooter;
}
```

Comment: And do not forget to hide the Footer of UITableView or so when UITextField becomes first-responder, and when it resigns to show that back.

Comment: Thx for your code but the header and footer of a table scroll with the table right? If I want them always visible I need seperate views don't I?

Comment: I guess they do not actually scroll with the table, or at least I think there may be some tricks to make them not to do so. The problem is that when the text-field becomes first responder, the footer will appear on top of the keyboard, and on top of it, the actual text-field. Therefore, you may do some tricks for hiding-unhiding the footer when needed.